# I have to put horizontally this div to the center. How can I do that?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, model-view-controller

```
<div class="row text-center table-bordered">
  @foreach (var moto in Model) {
  <div class="" style="background-color:white; border:solid; border-color:black; border-width:2px; margin-bottom:20px;">
    <a href='@Url.Action("Details", new {bikeID=moto.Moto_Model,Brand=moto.Moto_Brand})'>
      <h6 style="text-align:center; color:black; text-decoration:none;">@moto.Moto_Brand @moto.Moto_Model</h6>
      <div class="col-12">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="@moto.Moto_img" style="height:125px;width:200px;border-width:1px; ">
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  }
</div>
```

I tried justify-center content center text-center but it's like this :

```
|O O O |
```

I Want it like this :

```
| O O O |
```

But i couldn't figure it out... I'm getting data from EF but i want to put them like triple and triple when i use justify center 2 bike models remaining in the end and it's like |..o..o..| i want it to be |.O.O...| got that?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
.text-center{
  width: 100%; 
}
.text-center>div{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  justify-items: center;
}
```

Comment: see my modification

Answer (score 0):

This?

```
<h6 style="text-align:center; color:black; text-decoration:none;"><div class="mx-auto">@moto.Moto_Brand</div><div class="mx-auto">@moto.Moto_Model</div></h6>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which Bootstrap version your, but if I read `<div class="col-12">` I guess Bootstrap 4.

**Based on that:**

You can add class `col-4` to the div (your bike element) with `style="background-color:white; border:solid; border-color:black; border-width:2px; margin-bottom:20px;"`.

Default grid is 12 columns, so 12 divided by 3 elements is 4.

Also Bootstrap 4 has a pretty good [grid docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/) you may want to read.

> **If you want to center you bike elements:**
>   You also have to add `justify-content-center` to the div with `row` class to center the last two elements like you describe. (I did this in the example code snippet below)

**NOTE:**
The current columns classes (`col-4`) I added to this code example are not mobile-friendly aka resizing with your screen size. You want to consider something like this `col-12 col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-5` so your bike elements are resizing with the screen.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row text-center table-bordered justify-content-center">
  <div class="col-4" style="background-color:white; border:solid; border-color:black; border-width:2px; margin-bottom:20px;">
    <a href='@Url.Action("Details", new {bikeID=moto.Moto_Model,Brand=moto.Moto_Brand})'>
      <h6 style="text-align:center; color:black; text-decoration:none;">@moto.Moto_Brand @moto.Moto_Model</h6>
      <div class="col-12">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="@moto.Moto_img" style="height:125px;width:200px;border-width:1px; ">
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="col-4" style="background-color:white; border:solid; border-color:black; border-width:2px; margin-bottom:20px;">
    <a href='@Url.Action("Details", new {bikeID=moto.Moto_Model,Brand=moto.Moto_Brand})'>
      <h6 style="text-align:center; color:black; text-decoration:none;">@moto.Moto_Brand @moto.Moto_Model</h6>
      <div class="col-12">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="@moto.Moto_img" style="height:125px;width:200px;border-width:1px; ">
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="col-4" style="background-color:white; border:solid; border-color:black; border-width:2px; margin-bottom:20px;">
    <a href='@Url.Action("Details", new {bikeID=moto.Moto_Model,Brand=moto.Moto_Brand})'>
      <h6 style="text-align:center; color:black; text-decoration:none;">@moto.Moto_Brand @moto.Moto_Model</h6>
      <div class="col-12">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="@moto.Moto_img" style="height:125px;width:200px;border-width:1px; ">
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
    <div class="col-4" style="background-color:white; border:solid; border-color:black; border-width:2px; margin-bottom:20px;">
    <a href='@Url.Action("Details", new {bikeID=moto.Moto_Model,Brand=moto.Moto_Brand})'>
      <h6 style="text-align:center; color:black; text-decoration:none;">@moto.Moto_Brand @moto.Moto_Model</h6>
      <div class="col-12">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="@moto.Moto_img" style="height:125px;width:200px;border-width:1px; ">
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
    <div class="col-4" style="background-color:white; border:solid; border-color:black; border-width:2px; margin-bottom:20px;">
    <a href='@Url.Action("Details", new {bikeID=moto.Moto_Model,Brand=moto.Moto_Brand})'>
      <h6 style="text-align:center; color:black; text-decoration:none;">@moto.Moto_Brand @moto.Moto_Model</h6>
      <div class="col-12">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="@moto.Moto_img" style="height:125px;width:200px;border-width:1px; ">
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```